# R to BigQuery Data Upload Error

Tags: r, google-bigquery

I'm using the R package "bigrquery" to upload data from an R data frame into an existing BigQuery table as follows:

```
mybq = bq_table(project='...', dataset='...', table=...)
bq_table_upload(x=mybq, values=..., create_disposition='CREATE_NEVER', 
                write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND')
```

But I'm the following error message:

> Error: Invalid schema update. Field NewID has changed type from STRING to INTEGER

BigQuery appears to be auto-detecting the data format and mistakenly thinks the NewID column, which has values like "00487", is numeric when it's actually a string. When I append an "x" character to the NewID values, then the error goes away and the upload functions perfectly. Is there any way to disable the auto-detection when uploading data using the "bigrquery" package?

Comment: maybe convert NewID column into character class using `as.character` before uploading?

Comment: It's already a character in R. Otherwise it can't have leading zeros. The corresponding column in the BigQuery table is a STRING data type. The problem is the auto-detection that ignores the explicit data type; I can't figure out how to turn that feature off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `bq_perform_load` function in the same library should be a solution for this. In this function you can specify the schema with parameter `fields` so Bigquery will not auto-detect schema as explained [here](https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery/blob/master/R/bq-perform.R#L179).

I tested and it worked on my end. I created a table with two columns (STRING, STRING) and this is my source data:

```
0017    0015
0123    1234
1022    1202
```

I run the following command in R to make it work:

```
bq_perform_load('MY_PROJECT.MYDATASET.MYTABLE', "MY_GCS_OBJECT_LINK", nskip = 0, fields = list(bq_field("test1", "string"),bq_field("test2", "string")) , source_format = "CSV",create_disposition = "CREATE_NEVER", write_disposition = "WRITE_APPEND")
```

**Note:** I tried it at first time to run the same command with `fields = NULL` and it failed.

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful.

Comment: I am getting an error `Error: Source URI must be a Google Cloud Storage location` while using the above code. I have created a bucket on GCS. How can I direct R to specify the source. Thanks.

Comment: @PriyankaIndapurkar you should give a fully-qualified url as explained [here](https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery/blob/master/R/bq-perform.R#L161). How are you specifying the source_url param?